# How do you hide a field if other field's condition is not met in django?

Tags: python, django

So if I have this code in my models.py

```
class Computer(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=225)
```

How do I show either of the following additional field in my django admin depending on the value of brand above?

```
mac_os_version = models.CharField(max_length=225)
windows_os_version = models.CharField(max_length=225)
linux_os_version = models.CharField(max_length=225)
```

e.g. if brand == HP only the field for windows_os or linux will be shown when you try to input your data in the admin and will the hide field for mac_os.

Comment: Is brand pre determined or self populating or is it user input. Also are you talking about a dropdown form field or something of the like?

Comment: They’re user input.

Comment: What are your "mac_os", "windows_os" and "linux" fields for ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers they're fields to enter the version of your os. So if your computer is a mac you don't need the fields for windows and linux. Although they're just examples.

Comment: @Arcee I'm not sure this is the best design... I don't have enough context (who will use this application and what it's used for), but: 1/ most people will have one single OS installed, so it could be modeled with one "os" field and one "version" field, 2/ some people WILL have a multiboot, and then possibly with 2 or more versions of a same OS, 3/ the brand doesn't mean much (except that you probably won't have MacOS on a PC, but I know of some Mac running Linux...) - , 4/ "Linux" is not enough - you have to mention the distro -, and 5/ there are other OS (NetBSD, FreeBDS, OpenBSD etc).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I'm sorry if I caused a little confusion those codes are just examples. Not a real application that I'm trying to build... I tried my best to update the variables to be easily understood. Just want to know how to hide a field that depends on the condition of the other field. Example if you fill in the brand field with 'machintosh' only the mac_os_version field will show up in the django admin and will hide the other two.

Answer (score 1):

You could override the clean method in **admin.py**:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def clean(self):

    windows = {'HP','otherbrand1','otherbrand2'}

    if self.cleaned_data['brand'] in windows and \ 
    (self.cleaned_data['mac_os'] or self.cleaned_data['linux']):
        raise ValidationError('Only windows is allowed')

    return self.cleaned_data
```

`cleaned_data` is a dict of values that have been validated by the form. Therefore, you're validating that someone doesn't enter a value for fields `mac_os` or `linux` if a windows brand was specified beforehand.

Note that this will not be the exact behavior you were expecting. Indeed, this will only raise an error message to the user if he tries to save the model. If you absolutely need to have an in-time solution, you'll need more JS than Django code.